# removeEventListener not removing function

Tags: javascript, html5-video, dom-events, event-listener

This works, `timeListener` is removed every time:

```
var timeListener;
var setPause = function (time) {
    var video = $("video").get(0);
    timeListener = function (){
        if (video.currentTime >= time && video.currentTime < (time + 0.3)) {
            video.pause();
        }
    }
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeListener);
    video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeListener, false);
};
```

Only it's not what I want, because I obviously don't want to remove the event listener immediately. I want it to do it's work and then remove the old listener when the next video loads.

However, when I do this:

```
var timeListener;
var setPause = function (time) {
    var video = $("video").get(0);
    timeListener = function (){
        if (video.currentTime >= time && video.currentTime < (time + 0.3)) {
            video.pause();
        }
    }
    video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeListener, false);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeListener);
 };
```

`removeEventListener` doesn't work, and I end up with a video tag with multiple listeners attached.

It's my understanding that you have to store a reference to the function so that *exactly* the same function is being removed as the one that was added. The only difference between these 2 bits of code, I think, is that in the latter, `time`'s value has changed by the time `setPause` is called the second time and since the first instance has closure access to a different value for `time` it's considered different and not getting removed. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I solved the problem by calling `removeEvenetListener` in a different function called by `onClick` (actually `ng-click` but same thing) *before* the value for `time` is changed. So the problem, as I suspected, was that when the `timeListener` function has access to different variable values via closure it is considered a different function.

Been stuck on that problem for literally weeks so this has made my day!

Comment: having the same issue here but I didn't follow your line of thought